# Усложнённая квадратурная формула прямоугольника и правило Рунге

Tags: c++, математика

Нужно по усложнённой квадратурной формуле посчитать значение заданного интеграла с заданной точностью `eps = 0,001`.

 Саму формулу я реализовал, с увеличением числа разбиений `n` интеграл считается более точно.

 Но вот я совсем не уверен, правильно ли реализовано правило Рунге.

 Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли реализована программа и как её исправить, если неправильно.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

typedef double(*pointFunct) (double);

double f(double x)
{
    return exp(x*x*x);
}

double Integ(pointFunct f, double a, double b, int n)
{
    double I = 0.0;
    double h = (b - a) / n;

    for (double i = a; i < b; i += h)
    {
        I += f(i - 1 / 2)*h;
    }

    return I;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    double e = 0.001;
    double a = 1.0;
    double b = 2.0;
    double I = 0.0, I1 = 0.0;
    int n;

    cout << "Введите число разбиений: ";
    cin >> n;

    I1 = Integ(f, a, b, n);

    cout << "Приближённое значение интеграла равно: " << I1 << endl;

    do {
        I = I1;
        n = 2 * n;
        I1 = Integ(f, a, b, n);
    } while (fabs(I - I1) * (1 / 3) > e);

    cout << "Приближённое значение интеграла по правилу Рунге равно: " << I1 << endl;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, `1 / 2` равно `0`, то есть никакого смысла в вычитании под `f(i - 1 / 2)` нет. Во-вторых, почему вообще делается вычитание `1 / 2`? Если вы хотели вычислить `f` в середине отрезка, то вычитать нужно было половину `h`. Далее `1 / 3` тоже равно `0`, поэтому в `fabs(I - I1) * (1 / 3) > e` тоже делается ерунда.

Comment: @AnT то есть тогда получается интеграл мне нужно посчитать так I += f(i - h / 2)*h; Верно? А в формуле fabs(I - I1) * (1 / 3) > e вместо 1 / 3 задать заранее какое-нибудь число, которому присвоить значение 1 / 3.

Comment: @EgaNator: `1. / 3` даст вам правильное значение. Но можно же и просто написать `fabs(I - I1) / 3`.